# Is there a way to charge focus abilities faster?

Tags: warframe

Recently having completed the Second Dream quest, I've now unlocked some *very* powerful abilities. However, the 180 second cooldown on these abilities is quite long, and I'm wondering, is there any way it can be shortened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you check your focus tree (via your tenno in their fancy chair) you'll see the various schools of focus. If you access your currently active one you'll be able to see the various upgrades for that focus ability, one of the upgrades will let you reduce the cooldown timer.

(edit) Just make sure you have the appropriate lens installed in your warframe/weapon to accrue focus points so you can actually unlock the upgrades.